# Why does this int array throw an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I feel like an idiot for asking this but I can't for the life of me figure out why this IndexOutOfRangeException is happening. (I mean, i know *WHY* it's happening, I just don't know what is invalid about my code) Check the code below for where the error is being thrown:

```
public int[, ,] FindTablePairings(System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mcBegin, System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mcEnd)
    {
        int[,,] intTablePairs = new int[mcBegin.Count, 1, 1];
        int[] intBegin = new int[mcBegin.Count];
        int[] intEnd = new int[mcBegin.Count];

        for (int q = 0; q < mcBegin.Count; q++)
        {
            intBegin[q] = mcBegin[q].Index;
        }
        for (int q = 0; q < mcEnd.Count; q++)
        {
            intEnd[q] = mcEnd[q].Index;
        }

        int intBeginCount = mcBegin.Count;
        int intEndCount = mcEnd.Count;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        while (i < intBeginCount)
        {
            j = i;
            while (j < intEndCount)
            {
                if (intBegin[i + 1] < intEnd[j])
                {
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    intTablePairs[i, 0, 0] = intBegin[i];
                    intTablePairs[i, 1, 0] = intEnd[j];
                    intEnd[j] = -1;                         //EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == intEndCount)
            {
                intTablePairs[i, 0, 0] = intBegin[i];
                intTablePairs[i, 1, 0] = intEnd[j - 1];
                intEndCount--;
            }

            while (k < intEndCount)
            {
                if (intEnd[k] == -1)
                {
                    k++;
                }
                else
                {
                    intTablePairs[i,0,0] = intBegin[i];
                    intTablePairs[i,1,0] = intEnd[k];
                    intEnd[k] = -1;
                    k=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return intTablePairs;
    }
```

The code is just looking at character indexes of occurrences of beginning tags and ending tags. Nothing super complicated...but the worst part is that the exception is thrown at `intEnd[j] = -1;`, and in the Debugger, before that statement is executed, all the arrays and MatchCollections are properly initialized and populated, including `intEnd[]`! I've debugged to make sure the array exists and is initalized, and I've also cleaned the solution and rebuilt it.

Anybody have any suggestions as to what's going on here??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the error is actually on this line

```
intTablePairs[i, 1, 0] = intEnd[j];
```

The problem here is that you've defined the length of last 2 dimensions to both be 1 on `intTablePairs`.  Using the index 1 is hence invalid as it's equal to the length.  It seems like you meant to define the bounds as

```
int[,,] intTablePairs = new int[mcBegin.Count, 2, 2];
```

Comment: @AS-CII that can't be an error though else the line directly above it would also error.  Both access `intEnd[j]`.

Comment: I didn't write your solution was wrong ;) I thought he had made a mistake copying his code into StackOverflow.

Comment: @AS-CII that could definitely be the case. Have to wait and see what the OP says :)

Comment: Ah. Debugger was highlighting the line below it but you're right, the error is happening at the line you indicated. BRB.

Comment: Had a chance to test it...sure enough this was the problem! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at this:

```
 int[] intEnd = new int[mcBegin.Count];
```

Replace mcBegin on mcEnd and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `intEnd` should be set with `mcEnd.Count` capacity. So instead of:

```
int[] intEnd = new int[mcBegin.Count];
```

You should have:

```
int[] intEnd = new int[mcEnd.Count];
```

Hope it helps.